# Can't retrieve data from get function

Tags: node.js, lambda, https, get, alexa-skills-kit

I am writting a lambda function to handle alexa skill request. Inside 'BuildingLookUpIntent', after https.get(), nothing is added into response.

```js
'BuildingLookUpIntent': function(){
        var response = "";
        https.get('https://*******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/active/building?*******', (res) => {
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                response += d;
            });
        });  

        var speechOutput = response;
        this.response.speak(speechOutput);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
```

Alexa returns a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa would say nothing in your case. This is because 
`

```
 var speechOutput = response;
 this.response.speak(speechOutput);
 this.emit(':responseReady');
```

`
is executed even before your code would start processing the response received. 
One way to resolve this is to move the above mentioned code inside 
"**res.on**" , so that when you get the response string back it gets assigned to 
"**speechOutput**" and Alexa can speak that out.